# Use Meteor Template variables outside of Template declorations

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'd like to use variables related to specific Meteor Templates outside of the Template scope. Is this possible?

For example:

```
main.html:
<head>
<title>{{title}}</title>
</head>

<template name="Layout">
... layout code ...
{{> yield content}}
</template>

<template name="Home">
... code ...
</template>

<template name="Page2">
... code ...
</template>
```

Using Iron Router, a given template may resolve to a different route. For each route, I'd like the title to change to reflect the route.

Currently, when a variable resolves in a template, it still doesn't resolve outside of the template--so the result is that the page's title ends up being "{{title}}".

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can not render variables like that outside the template. However you could do something like this.

```
    Template.body.onRendered(() => {
         Tracker.autorun(() => {
            document.title = Router.current().route.getName();
         });
    });
```

Comment: `onRendered()` didn't work. However, if I use `autorun()` by itself, the page title is updated appropriately. ... Perhaps I'm missing something, but `getName()` didn't work either.

Comment: I put in the "Router.current().route.getName();" as the docs stated to get the current route (see docs: https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router)

"A route's name is now accessible at route.getName() . In particular, you'll need to write Router.current().route.getName()."

I am not super familiar with Iron Router as I use Flow Router for most my projects. But if the title is updating with Tracker.autorun then you are heading in the right direction.

If you console.log any of the Router.current() object piece by piece does it return anything?